# Traversal of a binary tree: i cannot get right output in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am typing pre-order traversal and the output is just '1-';  I have looked through several other threads on this site but cannot seem to find my mistake. Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated!

````
class Node(object):
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.number = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class binarytree(object):
    
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = Node(root)

    def print_traversal(self, direction, start):
        if direction == 'pre_order':
            return self.pre_order(start, '')
        
    def pre_order(self, start, traversal):
        if start:
            traversal += (str(start.number) + '-' )
            self.pre_order(start.left, traversal)
            self.pre_order(start.right, traversal)
        return traversal

# main function
tree1 = binarytree(1)
tree1.root.left = Node(2)
tree1.root.right = Node(3)
tree1.root.left.left = Node(4)
tree1.root.left.right = Node(5)
tree1.root.right.left = Node(6)

print(tree1.print_traversal('pre_order', tree1.root))```
````

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
traversal += (str(start.number) + '-' )
```

assigns a new value to the local variable `traversal`; it does *not* modify the string already in `traversal`. Thus, the changes made in the recursive calls are never seen at the level above where they're made.